# how to merge or combine a column name based on date group in multiple rows using union in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join, union

I am working on generating reports on MySQL in combining multiple tables using a union query but it comes to a result it was not suitable for my expected one I have mentioned a query below

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT
    raw_material_payment.paying_date AS date,
    raw_materials.bill_no AS raw_material_bill_no ,
    raw_material_payment.paying_amount + raw_material_payment.less AS raw_material_payment ,
    "" AS billings_no ,
    "" AS billing_payment ,
    "" AS expense_no ,
    "" AS expense_payment ,
    "" AS old_payment_no ,
    "" AS old_payment
  from raw_materials
  INNER JOIN raw_material_payment on raw_material_payment.raw_material_id = raw_materials.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    billings.date AS date ,
    "" AS raw_material_bill_no ,
    "" AS raw_material_payment ,
    billings.id AS billings_no ,
    billing_payments.paying_amount + billing_payments.less AS billing_payment ,
    "" AS expense_no ,
    "" AS expense_payment ,
    "" AS old_payment_no ,
    "" AS old_payment
  FROM billings
  INNER JOIN billing_payments on billing_payments.billing_id=billings.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    expense.bill_date AS date ,
    "" AS raw_material_bill_no ,
    "" AS raw_material_payment ,
    "" AS billings_no ,
    "" AS billing_payment ,
    expense.bill_no AS expense_no ,
    "" AS expense_payment ,
    "" AS old_payment_no ,
    "" AS old_payment
  FROM expense
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    old_payments.bill_date AS date ,
    "" AS raw_material_bill_no ,
    "" AS raw_material_payment ,
    "" AS billings_no ,
    "" AS billing_payment ,
    "" AS expense_no ,
    "" AS expense_payment ,
    old_payments.bill_no AS old_payment_no ,
    old_payments.total AS old_payment
  FROM old_payments
) as report GROUP BY date,raw_material_bill_no,billings_no,expense_no,old_payment_no;
```

it comes as a result

[image]

I Need a Combine column value based on the date like this

[image]

A single Row contains all the field values in one row based on the date

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why `UNION ALL`? Why don't you just join the tables on date instead? Is the problem that all tables are optional for a date, so you'd need a full outer join that MySQL still doesn't support?

Comment: You say "I Need a Combine column value based **on the date**", but your expected result shows two rows for the same date. Why is that? When do you want more than one result row per date? And please adjust your sample data and result, so they match, i.e. show the expected result for the sample data instead of an unrelated result.

Comment: It was just for example of the expected result as i given it was not a original one

Comment: ... which doesn't answer any of the questions. It is not clear what exactly you want to achieve. One result row per date? One result row per date and ___? Is one of the tables a base table that is guaranteed to have a row for every such group or not? What to do about the different old_payment_no for one date?

Comment: I understand i will add a clear explanation

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you describe a `SUM(columnName) AS columnName` based on a `GROUP BY dateColumn`.

Which begs the question: consider the date of `2023-07-10`, where you have several rows, whose `old_payment_no` values are shown as INV001, INV002 and several empty values (other columns have multiple values too). Which value should go in the *single cell* of old_payment_no corresponding to that date? The lexicographically highest? The lowest? All of them using `GROUP_CONCAT()`?